# GAS: How to use strings in databse querys?

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to query in my script my database. The query's parameters depends on what I have defined in my GUI. Sometimes I like to use the NAME in query and sometimes the CITY. Here is the code:

```
  var query = 'STRUCTTYPE: PERSON';

  if (value1 != 0) {
    query = query + ', NAME: ' + value1;
  }
  if (value2 != 0) {
    query = query + ', CITY: ' + value2;
  }
```

So the string 'query' itself is ok, but when I try to use it in db.query I get error message.

```
var results = db.query(query);
```

Any suggestions? Or other ways to handle this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `query` parameter you pass to `ScriptDb.query` function must be an `object`, not a `string`. Try this:

```js
var query = {STRUCTTYPE: 'PERSON'};
if( value1 != 0 ) //this != 0 seems a weird test, but I'm copying from your example
  query.NAME = value1;
if( value2 != 0 )
  query.CITY = value2;

var results = db.query(query);
```